# data file not showing when the button is clicked(php)

Tags: php

so im supposed to get some text off the php file and i ran it through my server and it's not doing anything!

This is my JQ

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    findteacher = function() {

    var file = "course.php?course" + $("#course").val();

    $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : file,
    datatype : "text"
    success : function(response) {


    $("#courseInfo").html(response);
    }


        });
    }

        clear = function() {
        $("#courseInfo").html("");
        };

        $("#course").click(clear);
        $("#go").click(findteacher);
        });
```

my html

```
<title>Course Info</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Course Information Search</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="course" id="course">
    <option value="420-121">420-121</option>
    <option value="420-122">420-122</option>
    <option value="420-123">420-123</option>
    <option value="420-221">420-221</option>
    <option value="420-222">420-222</option>
    <option value="420-223">420-223</option>
    <option value="420-224">420-224</option>

<select>
Select a course to see the course name and teacher assigned<br><br>
<input type="button" id="go" value="go!">

</form>
<br><br>
<div id="courseInfo"></div>
 <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>    
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my php

```
  <?php
$filename = "data.txt";
try {
   if ($courses = @fopen($filename, "r")) {
    while (!feof($courses)) {
        $line = fgets($courses);
        $array = explode(", ", $line);

        if (trim($array[0]) == $_GET["course"])
            echo  $array[1] . ", " . $array[2];
    }
    fclose($courses);
   }
   else {
      throw new Exception('file not found.');
   }
}
catch (Exception $e){
   echo "Sorry, ",  $e->getMessage(), "<br>";
}
?>
```

can any one tell me why this is not working? where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: I think theres a  `=` missing here `"course.php?course" + $("#course").val();` after the `course`

Comment: okay it says  this line has an error  `success : function(response) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **syntax error** in Jquery snippet: `,` is missing missing after `datatype` attribute's value.

```
datatype : "text",
                 ^
success : function(response) {
```

---

**Suggestion:** Put`=` operator in GET parameter

```
"course.php?course=" + $("#course").val()
                  ^
```

Comment: everything is working now, no errors but nothing is showing up under the dropdown

Comment: I am glad it works. Enjoy scripting and learn debugging code by your self.